# Photos appear on iCloud but not on computer

Tags: icloud, photos, photos.app

I have 120,000 photos and videos successfully backed up on iCloud.

They however do not appear on my computer in my Photos library. In the library only about 20,000 appear and nothing after 2018.

- iCloud is turned on.
- I am logged in with the same Apple ID.
- No deleted photos.
- No hidden photos.

What am I missing? How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have enough room on your hard drive for all those photos?  What prompted you to check for this, were you doing an upgrade or something similar?  Do you have any other devices signed in with the same Apple ID that you can look for the photos?

Comment: Just a clarification: iCloud is a **syncing** service and **not** a backup. Backups are vital and worth spending money on, but iCloud will not be sufficient. If you delete/lose something on iCloud you will lose it and can't restore it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. How much time has passed since you started syncing? On Photos.app preferences, is iCloud Photos set to "Download Originals to this Mac" or "Optimize Mac Storage"?

Comment: @fsb I was combining different photo libraries as described here: https://www.citymac.com/blog/2019/05/09/need-to-merge-photos-libraries-here-are-your-options 
The merge did work on the cloud, but the photos are not missing in the local library. I do have enough space on my drive.

Comment: How long have you been waiting to see the photos on your machine?  Depending on the size of your photo library, it could many days to sync.  The syncing usually only happens on a backround thread so it's not a high priority task.  Make sure you keep your device awake, connected to the internet, and try not to use it.  After 3 days or so, check the status.